# How can I apply conditional filtering to MongoDB documents?

Tags: mongodb, filter, match

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to apply multiple levels of filtering to my mongoDB documents (not sure if this phrasing is correct).
I am trying to create an app that will allow users to perform a search and retrieve only those documents that match the filters they have chosen to apply. A user might chose to apply only one filter or combine multiple filters.

For example, the user might be looking for a house. The available filters could be location, size and type. If the user applies the location filter with a value of ‘London’, they should get only those houses available in London. If they choose to combine the above location with the type filter with a value of ‘2-bedroom-apartment’, they should get all 2-bedroom apartments available in London.

How can I make sure that the results are conditionally filtered, depending on the filters that the user has applied?
I think I am supposed to use [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), but I don’t understand if I can use multiple queries with it.

What I have come up with so far is the following:

```
const getFilteredData = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { filter1, filter2, filter3 } = req.query;
        const filteredData = await dataModel.aggregate([
            {$match:{
                $and:[{filter1:filter1},{filter2: filter2}, {filter3:filter3}]    //1st option: all of the filters are applied by the user
            }}
        ])
        res.status(201).json({data: filteredData});
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(404).json({message: err.message});
    }
}
```

With the above code, the results are filtered only when all 3 filters are being applied. How can I cater to different combinations of filters being applied by the user (only one filter, filter1 & filter3 combined etc)?

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: Since you build your query in your code, you can add or remove filters to the array in your code, according to what the user wanted. No need to handle it inside the query...

Comment: If you provide a specific example of sample data and filters I'll show how

Comment: Thanks for the response @nimrod. At the moment I have 3 documents in my offeredItems collection.

{
"name": "Table",
"category": "Furniture",
"description": "Wooden table",
"condition": "Slightly used",
"city": "Athens"
},
{
"name": "Coat",
"category": "Clothing",
"description": "Long beige raincoat",
"condition": "Slightly used",
"city": "Athens"
},
{
"name": "Boots",
"category": "Clothing",
"description": "Yellow children's boots",
"condition": "Slightly used",
"city": "Thessaloniki"
}

The filters that the user can apply are: item name, city, category

Comment: And please provide an example for `req.query`

Comment: @nimrodserok just as in the generic example I provided above, but instead of filter1, filter2 and filter3 I have
const { name, city, category } = req.query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `req.query` can be `{name: "Coat", city: "Athens"}` You can do something like:

```
const getFilteredData = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const filtersArr = [];
        for (const filterKey of ['name', 'city', 'category']) {
            if (req.query[filterKey]) {
                const thisFilter = {};
                thisFilter[filterKey] = req.query[filterKey];
                filtersArr.push(thisFilter);
            }
        }
        console.log(filtersArr)
        const filteredData = await filteredDataModel.aggregate([
            {$match:{
                $and: filtersArr    //1st option: all of the filters are applied by the user
            }}
        ])
        res.status(201).json({data: filteredData});
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(404).json({message: err.message});
    }
}
```

You can also use the original req.query like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fVLxM9jhYmI):

```
const filteredData = await filteredDataModel.find(req.query)
```

But iterating using the code allows you to validate the keys that you want...

Comment: Thank you so much @nimrod! For some reason I couldn't get it to work with aggregate, but using find worked just fine!

Comment: Please attach a link to the mongo playground with the aggregation example

Comment: I'm sorry Nimrod, I'm not sure I understood what you're asking for. I'm not familiar with mongo playground.

Comment: The link in my answer is leading to it. If you'll attach a link with your aggregation query, I'll see why it does not work

Comment: I just used match just as you did in your example. Like that I guess?(https://mongoplayground.net/p/FrOQF_MiHQn). I tested it on Postman and I was getting an error saying that the array was empty.

Comment: We want it to be like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s5Ya2xJ5Jtt). Updated the answer accordingly.